# jQuery with mustache sorting from an array issue

Tags: jquery, sorting, mustache

I created a few templates using Mustache (0.7.2/) / jQuery (2.1.3) and wanted to sort the array based on a selection from the dropdown. I can't even get the array to refresh using Mustache.

I'm not a developer so I'm kind of shooting in the dark on most of this. just wanted something quick and dirty for my prototype.  here is dumb'ed down example of what I'm trying to.

https://codepen.io/gzuiderweg/pen/XvpXxy

Mustache Template:

```
    <script type="text/template" id="sumview">

    {{#panels}}

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">{{company-name}}<br/>{{prod-name}}</div>
            <div class="col-2">{{version-count}}</div>
            <div class="col-2">{{issue-count}}</div>
            <div class="col-2">{{injury-count}}</div>
            <div class="col-2">{{malfunction-count}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {{/panels}}

     </script>
```

HTML:

```
    <select id="sort">
    <option selected>Sort By</option>
    <option value="company-name">Company Name</option>
    <option value="prod-name">Product Name</option>
    <option value="version-count">Version Count</option>
    <option value="issue-count">Issue Count</option>
    <option value="injury-count">Injury Count</option>
    <option value="malfunction-count">Malfunction Count</option>
    </select>

    <div class="view-summary" id="sumview-container">
    </div>
```

jQuery

```
    var template = $('#sumview').html();  
    var outputsum = $('#sumview-container');
    var data = {

    "panels": [

    { "company-name": "Acme", "prod-name": "productA", "version-count": "2", "issue-count": "1", "injury-count": "5", "malfunction-count": "10" },

    { "company-name": "BankA", "prod-name": "productB", "version-count": "15", "issue-count": "6", "injury-count": "2", "malfunction-count": "8" },

    { "company-name": "CorpA", "prod-name": "productC", "version-count": "6", "issue-count": "9", "injury-count": "4", "malfunction-count": "1" }


       ]
     }


    var resultSum = Mustache.render(template, data)
        outputsum.append(resultSum);
```

I have tried varies jquery sort function like:

```
    $("#sort").on("change", function () {

    data.sort(function(a, b){
        var a1= a.company-name, b1= b.company-name;
        if(a1== b1) return 0;
        return a1> b1? 1: -1;

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method belongs to the Array prototype. In your case you are trying to sort `data` which is actually an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). You want to target your sort on the `data.panels` property, sort that array, then set `data.panels` to the array which you have sorted.

I think the real problem surfaces when you want to sort by number. The sort function needs to be able to distinguish number from string.

Also, you may want to determine in which direction you want to sort your numbers too. In this example I have defaulted to descending. You could change to what suits your needs.

```js
const data = {
  "panels": [
    {
      "company-name": "BankA",
      "prod-name": "productB",
      "version-count": "15",
      "issue-count": "6",
      "injury-count": "2",
      "malfunction-count": "8"
    },
    {
      "company-name": "Acme",
      "prod-name": "productA",
      "version-count": "2",
      "issue-count": "1",
      "injury-count": "5",
      "malfunction-count": "10"
    },
    {
      "company-name": "CorpA",
      "prod-name": "productC",
      "version-count": "6",
      "issue-count": "9",
      "injury-count": "4",
      "malfunction-count": "1"
    }
  ]
}

const sortBy = (key, array) => {
  return array.sort((a, b) => {
    const numericA = Number(a[key]);
    const numericB = Number(b[key]);
    if (!isNaN(numericA) && !isNaN(numericB)) {
      // a - b ascending sort
      // b - a descending sort
      return numericB - numericA;
    }
    return a[key].toLowerCase().localeCompare(b[key].toLowerCase());
  })
}

const renderTemplate = () => {
  $('#sumview-container').html(Mustache.render($('#sumview').html(), data));
}

$("#sort").on("change", function() {
  sortBy($(this).val(), data.panels);
  renderTemplate();
})

renderTemplate();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/3.0.1/mustache.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="sort">
  <option selected>Sort By</option>
  <option value="company-name">Company Name</option>
  <option value="prod-name">Product Name</option>
  <option value="version-count">Version Count</option>
  <option value="issue-count">Issue Count</option>
  <option value="injury-count">Injury Count</option>
  <option value="malfunction-count">Malfunction Count</option>
</select>

<div id="sumview-container"></div>

<script type="text/template" id="sumview">
  {{#panels}}
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">{{company-name}}<br/>{{prod-name}}</div>
      <div class="col-2">{{version-count}}</div>
      <div class="col-2">{{issue-count}}</div>
      <div class="col-2">{{injury-count}}</div>
      <div class="col-2">{{malfunction-count}}</div>
    </div>
  {{/panels}}
</script>
```

Comment: Cue. thank you for your response. you solved my weekend problem. you are the master!

Comment: @garrett I know I've provided a comprehensive example – but I do hope you research and learn what's provided in the solution. Best of luck.